Hyperref warning while changing color of section and subsection header text
I am trying to change the color of section/subsection header text with the newcommand hcol.
The color is changed (the section nrs not) , but I have hyperref error messages
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 69.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 70.

The code is below
\documentclass[man, donotrepeattitle, floatsintext, 12pt, a4paper]{apa7}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
 
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{color,soul}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage[american]{varioref}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 
 \setlist{nosep} % to kill all the vertical space in lists (enum, item)

% the title commands 
\title{(working title)\\
new concept
}

\shorttitle{Develop Computational Thinking}
\authorsnames{Surf Plan}
\authorsaffiliations{Educational Sciences {,} Summer}

\duedate{Aug-2025}

\authornote{Student number: \\
E-mail address: \\
Course code and name: \\
Supervisor: assistent prof. \\
Number of words: t.b.s\\
Date: 01-08-2025
}


\abstract{\lipsum[1][1-2]\\
\emph{max 250 words} }


% section numbering
\setcounter {secnumdepth}{4}

\definecolor{EMPTY}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{RED}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{GREEN}{RGB}{34,200,0}
\definecolor{TEAL}{RGB}{0, 139, 139}

% commands for section color
\newcommand{\hcol}[1]{{\color{TEAL}#1}}
 
% counter
\newcounter{p-cnt} \setcounter{p-cnt}{0}
\newcommand{\nextCnt}{\stepcounter{p-cnt}\arabic{p-cnt}}
\newcommand{\firstCnt}[1][1]{\setcounter{p-cnt}{#1}\arabic{p-cnt}}
\newcommand{\probl}[1]{\begin{description}
\item[Learning Point  \nextCnt] #1
\end{description}}

% change title page headers t0 place the OU logo
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{% <<<<<<<<<<<< added
    \lhead{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{OUlogo.png}}% your logo here <<<
    \rhead{} %\rhead{\thepage}% for page-nr 1
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{\hcol{Introduction} }
\subsection{\hcol{SUBSECTION}}

\end{document}


This are only warnings, not errors. You can avoid them with \newcommand{\hcol}[1]{{\texorpdfstring{\color{TEAL}}{}#1}}. But it would be better to adapt the sectioning command e.g. with titlesec to add the color generally instead of using a command in every heading.

I tried titlesec but get an error after \usepackage{titlesec} there is the message ```titlesec.sty:1635: Argume
nt of \subparagraph has an extra }.

\par
l.1635 \ttl@extract\subparagraph
?
Runaway argument?

